# Meaning of telegraph code in the song "Planetes"

Tags: guilty-crown

The song *Planetes* in *Guilty Crown* begins with some telegraph encoding, which I think is [Wabun code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wabun_code).

Here is the [YouTube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WY9vkhvVZC4).

My transcription is:

```
-•-• -••-- •-- --•-- •- --•-• •-•-- -•--•
```

which decodes to this:

> ni-yu-ya a-i-shi-te-ru

Niyuya didn't make sense. Did I get something wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It really is Wabun Code. The telegraph sequence at the start of the song was widely known and had been discussed on Japanese website, all of them says 「集｛しゅう｝　愛｛あい｝してる」 (Shu-u, ai-shi-te-ru) is the encoded message. [[1]](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1194560156) [[2]](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q14111229784) [[3]](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q10107806360) [[4]](http://www.nicovideo.jp/watch/sm18938537) [[5]](http://d.hatena.ne.jp/altair_u51/20120923/1348329699) [[6]](http://matome.naver.jp/odai/2134797121958660201/2134857251616086703)

If you take a look at the Wikipedia page you cited, the small ゃ ya, ゅ yu, ょ yo in the digraphs are encoded the same as regular や　ya, ゆ yu, よ yo.

So we can comparing your attempt at decoding:

```
-•-• -••-- •--
```

and the supposed coding of the message (shi-yu-u):

```
--•-• -••-- ••-
```

Listening to the telegraph sequence again to cross-check, while I can agree with Japanese fans' transcription of the 3rd mora `••-`, I could only hear 1 dash at the beginning for the first mora `--•-•`. And apparently, [the author of answer [1]](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1194560156) on Yahoo also encountered the same problem:

> ネタバレになってしまいますが、
> 「しゅう あいしてる」
> だそうです。桜満集のことですね。
>
> ただ、最初の音(？)が微妙に「にゅ」と解読されるようですが、「にゅう あいしてる」だと意味が通じないので「しゅう あいしてる」で間違いないとおもいます。

Translation:

> This is going to be a spoiler,
> but it seems to be "Shuu, I love you".
> "Shuu" here is referring to Ouma Shuu.
>
> However, although the first sound somewhat decodes to "nyuu", "nyuu aishiteru" doesn't really make sense, so I think it is definitely "Shuu aishiteru".

There is [this question](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q11137077736) on Yahoo Answer which says that apart from the Morse code at the beginning and at the end *(which I myself also confirm, but I don't bother to decode it)*, the asker feels that there are also Morse code playing in the background through out the song *(which I also feel there is something, but listening closely reveals nothing)*.

Comment: probably you would need to de-mix the song to get the telegraph in the middle, and even so it would be hard not to dismiss it as noise. So probably it would need a godly sound engineer or just ask the songwriters directly. Anyway, the internet is vast and awesome. Let's hope... XD

Comment: Looks like there really is a section from 1:30 to 1:42 which has Wabun code running in the background.

Answer (score 3):

I tried decoding it by looking at its length through soundwave graphs (Audacity, or Audition) and it definitely looks like "Ni-yu-u A-i-shi-te-ru" (Nyuu Aishiteru) as the original author said.

The problem with "Shuu, Aishiteru" is that Planetes was never a song from the original Guilty Crown, it was part of the Lost Christmas OVA which Shuu was never part of. Either EGOiST and their manager decided not to put it in the original and use what they have for Lost Christmas, or it is a whole different meaning.

I have also seen other people theorize that it is Riyu Aishiteru meaning "reason I love you" which is better, but "ri" is never in the code.

Comment: There actually is no problem with the song. EGOIST includes chelly, who is in persona of Inori Yuzuriha. It would make sense Inori would leave a message.